# How to set MS Chart LegendItem image size

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

I use Image from Resources to LegendItem in WinForms

```
var ImageName = "ImageName";
myChart.Images.Add(new NamedImage(ImageName, Resources.Image));
LegendItem legendItem = new LegendItem();
legendItem.Name = "legend text";
legendItem.Image = ImageName;
myChart.Legends[Legend.Name].CustomItems.Add(legendItem);
```

But the size of Image is too small.
How can I change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use custom LegendCell in this case. This means you define the cells for your LegendItem specifying their properties. Something like this:

```
LegendItem legendItem = new LegendItem();
LegendCell cell1 = new LegendCell();
cell1.Name = "cell1";
cell1.Text = "legend text";
// here you can specify alignment, color, ..., too
LegendCell cell2 = new LegendCell();
cell2.Name = "cell2";
cell2.CellType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.LegendCellType.Image;
cell2.Image = "path of your img";
cell2.Size = new Size(.....);
legendItem.Cells.Add(cell1);
legendItem.Cells.Add(cell2);
```