# .NET Charting Legend Marker Size

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, windows, charts

I'm using the DataVisualizations Charting control on a .NET Windows form project.  The problem I'm having is that when I print the chart the legend is not showing the series marker (actually it is kind of showing but it just looks like a darker pixel on the line).  When the chart is viewed on the form the markers are visible although they are not very large and do not seem to change in relation to the MarkerSize value for the series.  But when the chart is printed (on paper or to a PDF) the markers are not there.

This picture shows the view of the chart when viewed on the form.  As you can see the legend markers are sort of visible but still no where near what the actual series markers are.

[image: Viewing chart on form]

This image shows a PDF version of the same chart.  If you squint real hard you can see darker pixel in the center of the legend line.

[image: PDF printed chart]

How can I fix the legend markers so they actually show when printed and to make them larger in size?

Comment: I have doubts that you can do it in any direct way. The size of the legend markers actually does grow with the markersize, but very much slower. So one workaround would be to replace the real legend by one of your own where you use an image you draw on the fly. If you are interested I can maybe show you an example later today..

Comment: That'd be great if you could show an example.  Curious to see how it would look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there seems to be no way to control the Legend Markers you may need to create a custom Legend. Here is an example of how it may look in the `Form` and in a `PDF`:

[image][image]

I had to zoom out the PDF, so it looks a little thinner/lighter.

Here is a function that returns a `CustomLegend`:

```
Legend CustomCloneLegend(Chart chart, Legend oLeg)
{
    Legend newL = new Legend();
    newL.Position = oLeg.Position;  // copy a few settings:
    newL.Docking = oLeg.Docking;
    newL.Alignment = oLeg.Alignment;
    // a few numbers for the drawing to play with; you may want to use floats..
    int iw = 32; int iw2 = iw / 2;    int ih = 18; int ih2 = ih / 2;
    int ir = 12;  int ir2 = ir / 2;   int lw = 3;
    // we want to access the series' colors!
    chart.ApplyPaletteColors();
    foreach (Series S in chart.Series)
    {
        // the drawing code is only for linechart and markerstyles circle or square:
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(iw, ih);
        using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        using (Pen pen = new Pen(S.Color, lw))
        using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(S.Color))
        {
            G.DrawLine(pen, 0, ih2, iw, ih2);
            if (S.MarkerStyle == MarkerStyle.Circle)
                G.FillEllipse(brush, iw2 - ir2, ih2 - ir2, ir, ir);
            else if (S.MarkerStyle == MarkerStyle.Square)
                G.FillRectangle(brush, iw2 - ir2, ih2 - ir2, ir, ir);
        }
        // add a new NamesImage
        NamedImage ni = new NamedImage(S.Name, bmp);
        chart.Images.Add(ni);
        // create and add the custom legend item
        LegendItem lit = new LegendItem( S.Name, Color.Red, S.Name);
        newL.CustomItems.Add(lit);
    }
    oLeg.Enabled = false;
    return newL;
}
```

Here is how I call it:

```
Legend LC = CustomCloneLegend(chart3, L);
chart1.Legends.Add(LC);
```

A few notes:

- The code uses the `chart.ApplyPaletteColors()`. This is necessary to access the `Series` color.
- It also makes use of the little know classes `NamedImage` and `Chart.Images`. This is neccessary since setting any images in a `Chart` requires a string!
- If you want to enlarge the image you may need to use `LegendCells`. For an example [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16933534/how-to-set-ms-chart-legenditem-image-size)!
- I have coded the image drawing only for one `ChartType` (`Line`) and only two `MarkerStyles`.
- There are many ways to customize those [`CustomItems`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.legenditem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dd456711%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for more info..
- I did use the `Series.MarkerSize` but it is easy to adapt the code by setting `ir = S.MarkerSize;` etc inside the loop!
- You may need to copy a few more settings from your original legend to the custom legend than the 3 I did. I just noticed that you have set a `Font`..

Comment: This is absolutely perfect and what I needed.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a VB translation of TaW's solution. I added code to draw triangle markers and commented out the code that draws a line through each marker so it's easier for me to see the marker shape. Therefore, you either have to set the MarkerStyle for each series before calling this function, or else uncomment that line.

My graph has some extra series that draw ovals around data points.  I don't want to display those in the legend, so I only show a legend entry for series that have a named LegendText.  Those lines are commented out below, but you can uncomment them if you want the same behavior.

```
Public Function CustomCloneLegend(chart As Chart, oLeg As Legend) As Legend

    Dim newL As Legend = New Legend With {
        .Position = oLeg.Position,
        .Docking = oLeg.Docking,
        .Alignment = oLeg.Alignment,
        .Font = oLeg.Font
        }
    ' a few numbers for the drawing to play with'
    Dim iw As Integer = 16        
    Dim iw2 As Integer = iw / 2
    Dim ih As Integer = 16
    Dim ih2 As Integer = ih / 2
    Dim ir As Integer = 6
    Dim ir2 As Integer = ir / 2
    Dim lw As Integer = 3
    Dim lit As LegendItem
    ' point array for drawing triangles, can expand to other shapes'
    Dim pts(2) As Point

    ' we want to access the series colors!'
    chart.ApplyPaletteColors()
    For Each S As Series In chart.Series
        ir = S.MarkerSize
        ' the drawing code Is only for linechart And markerstyles circle, square, triangle'
        Dim bmp As Bitmap = New Bitmap(iw, ih)
        Using G As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
            Using pen As Pen = New Pen(S.Color, lw)
                Using Brush As SolidBrush = New SolidBrush(S.Color)
                    ' Commented out the next line: Makes it hard to see the marker 'shapes
                    'G.DrawLine(pen, 0, ih2, iw, ih2) '
                    Select Case S.MarkerStyle
                        Case MarkerStyle.Circle
                            G.FillEllipse(Brush, iw2 - ir2, ih2 - ir2, ir, ir)
                        Case MarkerStyle.Square
                            G.FillRectangle(Brush, iw2 - ir2, ih2 - ir2, ir, ir)
                        Case MarkerStyle.Triangle
                            pts(0) = New Point(iw2, ih2)
                            pts(1) = New Point(1, ih)
                            pts(2) = New Point(iw - 1, ih)
                            G.FillPolygon(Brush, pts)
                    End Select
                    ' add a New NamesImage '
                    Dim ni As NamedImage = New NamedImage(S.Name, bmp) 
                    chart.Images.Add(ni) 
                    ' create And add the custom legend item '

                    'Uncomment the If block to hide legend labels for series with no LegendText '
                    'If S.LegendText <> "" Then '
                    lit = New LegendItem(S.Name, Color.Red, S.Name) With {
                        .MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.None,
                        .ImageStyle = LegendImageStyle.Marker
                    }
                    newL.CustomItems.Add(lit)
                    'End If '

                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    Next
    oLeg.Enabled = False
    Return newL
End Function
```