# C# Is it possible to set the legend color rectangle thickness?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have setup a Chart and I use SeriesChartType.Range for my series.

But I don't want the thick color legends it gives.

Is it possible to set the legend color rectangle thickness?

[image]

Comment: No, the automatically created Legend doesn't let you change its elements (except the LegendText of a Series). You can however disable/delete the whole Legend and create a new one with items you can style in various ways, including new bitmaps or stuff your draw yourself..

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36614148/make-chart-legend-represent-two-colors/36619240?s=1|5.2990#36619240) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34487165/net-charting-legend-marker-size/34496091?s=2|5.1059#34496091) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35791944/how-to-add-data-table-with-legend-keys-to-a-ms-chart-in-c/35795254?s=5|1.8580#35795254) for various examples